# Custom word boundaries in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match words using a regular expression, but sadly the word boundary character (\b) does not include enough characters for my taste, so I want to add more. (in that precise case, the "+" character)

Here is what I used to have (it is C# but not very relevant) :

```
string expression = Regex.Escape(word);
Regex regExp = new Regex(@"\b" + expression + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This particular regex did not match "C++" and I thought it was a real bummer. So I tried using the \w character in a character class that way, along with the + character :

```
string expression = Regex.Escape(word);
Regex regExp = new Regex(@"(?![\w\+])" + expression + @"(?![\w\+])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But now, nothing gets matched... is there something I am missing?

Comment: Yep, sorry, just edited it to include the declaration of **expression**. My bad. **word** is a string. In the case of **word** being "C++", the expression becomes, after escaping: "C\\+\\+"

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"C\\+\\+"` instead of `"{C\\+\\+}"`? Forgive if I'm wrong. I'm new to C#.

Comment: Yes yes, sorry, edited it again :D I just looked inside the wrong element while debugging

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(no need to escape the `+` in a character class)

The problem is that you use a negative lookahead first whereas you should use a negative lookbehind. Try:

```
@"(?<![\w+])" + expression + @"(?![\w+])"
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I had a feeling the first statement should be different than the second, but it is hard to formulate such questions in a search engine

Comment: I browsed it for a while, but never stumbled upon the part about the "?" character... And sadly, your "\Q" character is not recognized by regex... at least in my language.

Comment: `(?=...)` and friends are in the lookarounds section. I thought .net had support for \Q and \E, but apparently not... Too bad :/