# Find integers and floats in SQL query string using Python and regex

Tags: python, sql, regex

I am working on a Python function that parses a string representing a SQL query and returns the numbers (both integers and floats). I need those to highlight the numbers in the GUI.

I use https://regex101.com/ to test the regular expressions I build and I have almost got it except when number is a part of a column name in the SQL query.

`[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`

would include even `pop1990` in `220, pop1990 in (5, 100, 7.8,25;)` which I want to avoid. It looks as I may need to use negations using `^` but not sure how it would work.

When searching for numbers, how do I exclude those cases when number comes right after a word character (`\w`) but still match when it comes before or after `(`, `,`, `;` and so forth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match entire words only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only)

Comment: @SebastianProske, I am looking for a way to match numbers, not to find entire words. How is the question you posted above helpful?

Comment: Well, you most likely will have to use some kind of custom word boundary using lookarounds, e.g. `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` - let me look for a better dupe target -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232931/custom-word-boundaries-in-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

https://regex101.com/r/BgEP7C/1

The regex is `(?<=[^\w])[\d\.]+`.

- `(?<=[^\w])` it's a **positive lookbehind**; it checks if what's behind the number is NOT a `\w`, but **it doesn't add it to the match**.
- `[\d\.]+` matches multiple numbers and `.` for the decimal point.

**Updated so it works with `+`, `-` and `e`:**

Link: https://regex101.com/r/BgEP7C/5

Regex: `(?i)(?<=[^\w])[-+]?[\d\.]+(e[-+]?\d+)?`

**REQUESTED EDIT**

The original version doesn't work in Python beacause of the `(e[-+]?\d+)?` part.

A version that workds in Python: `(?i)(?<=[^\w])[-+]?[\d\.]+e?[+-]?\d*`

Comment: Thanks, the first one works. Interestingly enough, the second expression returns nothing in Python 3.5. Try `import re
re.findall("(?i)(?<=[^\w])[-+]?[\d\.]+(e[-+]?\d+)?", 'pop1990 in (5,100,5)')`, getting `['', '', '']` back

Comment: You're right. Apparently the problem is this part `(e[-+]?\d+)?`. `(?i)(?<=[^\w])[-+]?[\d\.]+e?[+-]?\d*` works. You want me to add it to the answer?

Comment: Try `re.findall("(?i)(?<=[^\w])[-+]?[\d\.]+e?[+-]?\d*", 'pop1990 in (5,100,5)')`